# Floating action button in Constraint Layout

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, floating-action-button

I have got three Constraint Layout inside a Master Constraint Layout which is inside a Scroll View.

So basically the structure is like:

```
<NestedScrollView>
    <ConstraintLayout>
       <ConstraintLayout>
       </ConstraintLayout>
       <ConstraintLayout>
       </ConstraintLayout>
       <ConstraintLayout>
       </ConstraintLayout>
    </ConstraintLayout>
</NestedScrollView>
```

This is just to give an idea of the structure. I need a floating action button to be visible at the bottom of the screen through out the scroll view. Just like in the image below. How do i achieve it?

[image]

Comment: Wrap your scrollview in a framelayout, and add the FAB as a second child of the framelayout (sibling to the scrollview)

Comment: You can just stick it in the top-level ``ConstraintLayout``, after the nested one, and constrain it to the bottom right. If it's defined later in the XML it should be drawn on top, or setting ``elevation`` to a higher value than the sibling layout (which should already be set by default if you're using a ``Floating ActionButton`` widget, elevation is part of its default styling)

Comment: when i do this, the FAB is at the bottom of the scroll view as the top-level ConstraintLayout extend to the bottom @cactustictacs

Comment: It's at the bottom in your screenshot too. If you mean it's *below* the ``ConstraintLayout``'s bottom, then either you haven't put it inside the top ``ConstraintLayout``, or you haven't set the constraints right (right/end to ``parent``, bottom to ``parent``, ``16dp`` margin is the material spec

Comment: I went with @benP's solution and it seems to work, thanks!